# How to make Shiny bs4Dash boxes sortable

Tags: r, shiny, module, namespaces, bs4dash

I have coded a small modularised shiny app with sortable boxes from bs4Dash, however, I can’t get the boxes to drag (sortable), as they do on the online demo at https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/bs4DashDemo/. I am of the opinion that I have a namespace issue with the modules but I can’t figure out where. Any assistance please?

The end goal (for context) is to have sortable boxes that can have new boxes added and deleted via buttons (I will include further code later to read and write the notes via a csv between sessions). I am looking to move them around to arrange as priority tasks/notes.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

sortcard_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("outpt_card_cntrl"))
  )
}

sortcard <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$outpt_card_cntrl <- renderUI({
    
    ns <- session$ns
    box_id = environment(ns)[['namespace']]
    tags$div(id = box_id,
             tagList(
               sortable(width = 11,
                        box(title = paste0("Box No: ", box_id), 
                            width = 12,
                            textAreaInput(ns("add_text"), label = NULL, placeholder = "Add notes"))),
               column(1, actionButton(ns('deleteButton'), '',
                                      icon = shiny::icon('times'),
                                      style = 'float: right')))
    )
  })
}

ui = dashboardPage(
  options = NULL,
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "sortablecards",
      fluidRow(actionButton('addButton', '', icon = icon('plus'))))
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
  title = ""
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  remove_shiny_inputs <- function(id, .input) {
    invisible(
      lapply(grep(id, names(.input), value = TRUE), function(i) {
        .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i)
      })
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$addButton, {
    
    i <- sprintf('%04d', input$addButton)
    id <- sprintf('srtcrd%s', i)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = '#addButton',
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = sortcard_UI(id)
    )
    
    callModule(sortcard, id)
    observeEvent(input[[paste0(id, '-deleteButton')]], {
      removeUI(selector = sprintf('#%s', id))
      remove_shiny_inputs(id, input)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, any work around you have found thus far? I've been able to get the UI to function properly by using large switch statements. In my example I allow a max of 4 boxes to be created by users. The logic will fill boxes

Comment: I don't recall finding a solution for it sorry.